# How can I access the action parameter passed to onSubmit SwiftUI modifier?

Tags: swiftui

SwiftUI provides onSubmit view modifier

```
extension View {
    public func onSubmit(of triggers: SubmitTriggers = .text, _ action: @escaping (() -> Void)) -> some View
}
```

I have my own `MyTextField` implementation which uses a `UITextField` under the hood due to validation needs (please don't pick on this point, this is not a part of the question).

```
Form {
    MyTextField()
}
.onSubmit {
    // some code here
}
```

I have got a delegate call from the UITextField when the Return button is pressed on the keyboard. I would like to trigger the action provided by the modifier. How can I access the `action` parameter from inside my implementation, so I could trigger it?

On a broader scope, how can I access any of those parameters passed to view modifiers implemented on View protocol? Where do they keep them?

Answer (score 1):

I have found an explanation in this article: https://www.fivestars.blog/articles/onsubmit/

- `onSubmit` adds a `TriggerSubmitAction` value into the environment
- Unfortunately, this environment value is not exposed to third party developers: the submit action cannot be triggered programmatically (FB9429770).

It would be great to have a more official reference. If anyone has more insights, please share them.